# Extend Symfony 2 cache:clear command to clear APC as well

Tags: php, caching, symfony, apc

Is there a way to extend Symfony 2 `cache:clear` command to clear APC as well or to do some other logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [ApcBundle](https://github.com/ornicar/ApcBundle) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

While ApcBundle will clear the cache, it will do so through a web endpoint, which you have to configure in the router and in webserver).
[CacheToolBundle](https://github.com/gordalina/CacheToolBundle) will register Symfony2 commands which you can use to clear the cache without having to setup the webserver.

You can check it out here: https://github.com/gordalina/CacheToolBundle